# Splitting all txt files in a folder into smaller files based on a regular expression using bash

Tags: regex, bash, text, split

I have a folder containing large text files. Each file is a collection of 1000 files separated by [[ *file name* ]]. I want to split the files and make 1000 files out of them and put them in a new folder. Is there a way in bash to do it? Any other fast method will also do.

```sh
for f in $(find . -name '*.txt')
do mkdir $f
  mv 
  cd $f
  awk '/[[.*]]/{g++} { print $0 > g".txt"}' $f
  cd ..
done
```

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do it. What have you tried on your own?

Comment: for f in $(find . -name '*.txt'); do mkdir $f; mv ;cd $f;awk '/\[\[.*\]\]/{g++} { print $0 > g".txt"}' $f;cd ..; done

Comment: but it gives an error that filename has been used in the folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to create a folder with the same name of the already existing file.

```
for f in $(find . -name '*.txt')
do mkdir $f
```

Here, "find" will list the files in the current path, and for each of these files you will try to create a directory with exactly the same name. One way of doing it would be first creating a temporary folder:

```
for f in $(find . -name '*.txt')
do mkdir temporary # create a temporary folder
  mv $f temporary # move the file into the folder
  mv temporary $f # rename the temporary folder to the name of the file
  cd $f # enter the folder and go on....
  awk '/[[.*]]/{g++} { print $0 > g".txt"}' $f
  cd ..
done
```

Note that all your folders will have the ".txt" extension. If you don't want that, you can cut it out before creating the folder; that way, you won't need the temporary folder, because the folder you're trying to create has a different name from the .txt file.
Example:

```
for f in $(find . -name '*.txt' | rev | cut -b 5- | rev)
```

Answer (score 0):

Although not awk and written and written by a drunk person, not guaranteed to  work.

```
import re
import sys


def main():
    pattern = re.compile(r'\[\[(.+)]]')
    with open (sys.argv[1]) as f:
        for line in f:
            m = re.search(pattern, line)
            if m:
                try:
                    with open(fname, 'w+') as g:
                        g.writelines(lines)
                except NameError:
                    pass
                fname = m.group(1)
                lines = []
            else:
                lines.append(line)

    with open(fname, 'w+') as g:
        g.writelines(lines)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a bash script.  Here, I've done it for you.

Notice the structure and features of this script:

- explain what it does in a `usage()` function, which is used for the `-h` option.
- provide a set of standard options: `-h`, `-n`, `-v`.
- use `getopts` to do option processing
- do lots of error checking on the arguments
- be careful about filename parsing (notice that blanks surrounding the file names are ignored.
- hide details within functions.  Notice the 'talk', 'qtalk', 'nvtalk' functions?  Those are from a bash library I've built to make this kind of scripting easy to do.
- explain what is going on to the user if in `$verbose` mode.
- provide the user the ability to see what would be done without actually doing it (the `-n` option, for `$norun` mode).
- never run commands directly. but use the `run` function, which pays attention to the `$norun`, `$verbose`, and `$quiet` variables.

I'm not just fishing for you, but teaching you how to fish.

Good luck with your next bash script.

Alan S.

```
#!/bin/bash
# split-collections IN-FOLDER OUT-FOLDER

PROG="${0##*/}"

usage() {
  cat 1>&2 <<EOF
usage: $PROG [OPTIONS] IN-FOLDER OUT-FOLDER

This script splits a collection of files within IN-FOLDER into
separate, named files into the given OUT-FOLDER.  The created file
names are obtained from formatted text headers within the input
files.

The format of each input file is a set of HEADER and BODY pairs,
where each HEADER is a text line formatted as:

    [[input-filename1]]
    text line 1
    text line 2
    ...
    [[input-filename2]]
    text line 1
    text line 2
    ...

Normal processing will show the filenames being read, and file
names being created.  Use the -v (verbose) option to show the
number of text lines being written to each created file.  Use
-v twice to show the actual lines of text being written.

Use the -n option to show what would be done, without actually
doing it.

Options
 -h       Show this help
 -n       Dry run -- do NOT create any files or make any changes
 -o       Overwrite existing output files.
 -v       Be verbose

EOF
   exit
}

talk()   { echo 1>&2 "$@" ; }
chat()   { [[ -n "$norun$verbose" ]] && talk "$@" ; }
nvtalk() { [[ -n "$verbose" ]] || talk "$@" ; }
qtalk()  { [[ -n "$quiet" ]]   || talk "$@" ; }
nrtalk() { talk "${norun:+(norun) }$@" ; }

error() { 
  local code=2
  case "$1" in [0-9]*) code=$1 ; shift ;; esac
  echo 1>&2 "$@"
  exit $code
}

talkf()   { printf 1>&2 "$@" ; }
chatf()   { [[ -n "$norun$verbose" ]] && talkf "$@" ; }
nvtalkf() { [[ -n "$verbose" ]] || talkf "$@" ; }
qtalkf()  { [[ -n "$quiet" ]]   || talkf "$@" ; }
nrtalkf() { talkf "${norun:+(norun) }$@" ; }

errorf()  { 
  local code=2
  case "$1" in [0-9]*) code=$1 ; shift ;; esac
  printf 1>&2 "$@"
  exit $code
}

# run COMMAND ARGS ...

qrun() {
  ( quiet=1 run "$@" )
}

run() {
  if [[ -n "$norun" ]]; then
    if [[ -z "$quiet" ]]; then
      nrtalk "$@"
    fi
  else
    if [[ -n "$verbose" ]]; then
      talk ">> $@"
    fi
    if ! eval "$@" ; then
      local code=$?
      return $code
    fi
  fi
  return 0
}

show_line() {
  talkf "%s:%d: %s\n" "$in_file" "$lines_in" "$line"
}

# given an input filename, read it and create 
# the output files as indicated by the contents
# of the text in the file

split_collection() {
  in_file="$1"
  out_file=
  lines_in=0
  lines_out=0
  skipping=
  while read line ; do
    : $(( lines_in++ ))

    [[ $verbose_count > 1 ]] && show_line

    # if a line with the format of "[[foo]]" occurs,
    # close the current output file, and open a new
    # output file called "foo"

    if [[ "$line" =~ ^\[\[[[:blank:]]*([^ ]+.*[^ ]|[^ ])[[:blank:]]*\]\][[:blank:]]*$ ]] ; then
      new_file="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"

      # close out the current file, if any
      if [[ "$out_file" ]]; then
        nrtalkf "%d lines written to %s\n" $lines_out "$out_file"
      fi

      # check the filename for bogosities
      case "$new_file" in 
        *..*|*/*) 
          [[ $verbose_count < 2 ]] && show_line
          error "Badly formatted filename"
          ;;
      esac

      out_file="$out_folder/$new_file"
      if [[ -e "$out_file" ]]; then
        if [[ -n "$overwrite" ]]; then
          nrtalk "Overwriting existing '$out_file'"
          qrun "cat /dev/null >'$out_file'"
        else
          error "$out_file already exists."
        fi
      else
        nrtalk "Creating new output file: '$out_file' ..."
        qrun "touch '$out_file'"
      fi

      lines_out=0
    elif [[ -z "$out_file" ]]; then

      # apparently, there are text lines before the filename
      # header; ignore them (out loud)
      if [[ ! "$skipping" ]]; then
        talk "Text preceding first filename ignored.."
        skipping=1
      fi

    else # next line of input for the file
      qrun "echo \"$line\" >>'$out_file'"
      : $(( lines_out++ ))
    fi
  done
}

norun=
verbose=
verbose_count=0
overwrite=
quiet=

while getopts 'hnoqv' opt ; do
  case "$opt" in
  h)  usage ;;
  n)  norun=1 ;;
  o)  overwrite=1 ;;
  q)  quiet=1 ;;
  v)  verbose=1 ; : $(( verbose_count++ )) ;;
  esac
done
shift $(( OPTIND - 1 ))

in_folder="${1:?Missing IN-FOLDER; see $PROG -h for details}"
out_folder="${2:?Missing OUT-FOLDER; see $PROG -h for details}"

# validate the input and output folders
#
# It might be reasonable to create the output folder for the 
# user, but that's left as an exercise for the user.

in_folder="${in_folder%/}"    # remove trailing slash, if any
out_folder="${out_folder%/}"

[[ -e "$in_folder" ]]  || error "$in_folder does not exist" 
[[ -d "$in_folder" ]]  || error "$in_folder is not a directory."
[[ -e "$out_folder" ]] || error "$out_folder does not exist."
[[ -d "$out_folder" ]] || error "$out_folder is not a directory."

for collection in $in_folder/* ; do
  talk "Reading $collection .."
  split_collection "$collection" <$collection 
done

exit
```